# Import emails from gmail into outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I just re-installed my Outlook but unfortunately I didn't save the data file with all my emails. Is there any way to sync the outlook with my gmail? To export the mails from my gmail and then import them into outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect to GMail via IMAP.

[To set up your Outlook 2007 client to work with Gmail](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77689)

Comment: tried doing that but I cannot connect to the server. it just says that the connection to the imap server failed and no emails come into my inbox

Comment: You have to enable IMAP in Gmail's web-based settings before it will let you connect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **IMAP** or **SMTP**

[Configuring Gmail in outlook](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77689)